# Javascript to hide a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I utilize Javascript to show "pages" of testimonials - so that when clicking a link it shows one set of DIV's and hides the others, thereby allowing me to cycle through content using numbered links. I have attached my code of the basic design, I am just not familiar with how to use JS to actually make it function. In searching SOF all I can find is examples using Jquery scripts, but I do not have a jquery.

The objective is that when you click the "1" link in the top right corner only the blurbs with "1's" will show on the page, same with clicking the "2" link, all the 1's and 3's will disappear and only the blurbs with the 2's will show.

**CSS**

```
@charset 'utf-8';
/* CSS Document */

body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

box {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width:950px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.testimonialnavigation {
    width:950px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

ul.testimonialpages {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right:30px;
}

.testimonialpages li a {
    float: right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#C82633;
    display:inline-block;
}

.testimonialpages li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #737373;

}

.testimonials {
    clear:both;
    width:875px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    min-height:50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding:15px;
}

.testimonials:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color:#D3D3D3;
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='teststyle.css' />
</head>
<body>



<div class="box">                      

    <div class="testimonialnavigation">
        <ul class="testimonialpages">
            <li><a href="" id="page1">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="page2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="page3">1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <br><br>


        <div class="container">

            <div id="content1" class="testimonials">
            <i>
            111111 111111 111111111 11111111111
            </i><br>
            <b>
            - 11111111111
            </b>
            </div>

            <div id="content2" class="testimonials">
            <i>
            11111 111111 1111111 11111111 1111111111
            </i><br>
            <b>
            - 11111111
            </b>
            </div>

            <div id="content3" class="testimonials">
            <i>
            22222 22222222 222222 2222222 222222222
            </i><br>
            <b>
            - 2222222
            </b>
            </div>

            <div id="content4" class="testimonials">
            <i>
            2222222 222222 2222222222 222222 2222222 222222
            </i><br>
            <b>
            - 222222
            </b>
            </div>

            <div id="content5" class="testimonials">
            <i>
            333333 3333333 33333333 33333333 333333 3 33333333 
            </i><br>
            <b>
            - 33333333
            </b>
            </div>

            <div id="content6" class="testimonials">
            <i>
            333333 33333333 333333 333333333333
            </i><br>
            <b>
            - 333333333
            </b>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not here to write code for you but to help you with code you wrote.

Comment: poor question, please STFW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hide

```
document.getElementById('id-of-some-element').style.display = 'none';
```

show

```
document.getElementById('id-of-some-element').style.display = 'block';
```

Consider to learn jQuery to do things easier.

You could even address the problem by using anchors (`href="#some-name-in-the-page"`) and the CSS selector `:active`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id with an href like this:

```
<a href="#mydiv">Take me to my div</a>    

<div id="mydiv"><p>Hello</p></div>
```

OR:

```
<a href="#mydiv">Take me to my div</a>    

<h2 id="mydiv">My Div!</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that using JQuery toggle. This will hide and show based on your specified selector. It could be a class or id or an element.

Example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(".testimonials").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.getElementById('page1').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementByClassNames('testimonials').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('content1').style.display = 'block';
});
</script>
```

Something like that would do the trick, obviously you need to either do something similar for each one, or refactor it to work for with each without breaking DRY principles.

Take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

and: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById